# push from HTML table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
var feed = {created_at: "2017-03-14T01:00:32Z", entry_id: 33358, field1: "4", field2: "4", field3: "0"};
var data = [];
data.push(feed);
console.log(data);
```

Can someone advice how to take one parameter from the table?
I want to do something like this:

```
var feed = {document.getElementById("tbl").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML: "2017-03-14T01:00:32Z", entry_id: 33358, field1: "4", field2: "4", field3: "0"};
```

thank you.

Comment: you can use `querySelector` to access your desired `tr` and again access your desired td cell by `querySelector` [read about querySelector()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('tbl').append("<tr><td>"+feed.created_at+"</td> 
<td>"+feed.entry_id+"</td><td>"+feed.field1+"</td><td>"+feed.field2+"</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first row and first column HTML like:

```
const key = document.querySelector('.tbl tr:first-child td:first-child').innerHTML
```

and then set this as object property like:

```
var feed = {
  [key]: "2017-03-14T01:00:32Z",
  entry_id: 33358,
  field1: "4",
  field2: "4",
  field3: "0"
};
```

Demo:

```js
const key = document.querySelector('.tbl tr:first-child td:first-child').innerHTML

const feed = {
  [key]: "2017-03-14T01:00:32Z",
  entry_id: 33358,
  field1: "4",
  field2: "4",
  field3: "0"
};

console.log(feed)
```

```html
<table class='tbl'>
  <tr>
    <td>created_at</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do you know how can i take value from variable? like this  var feed = {
 ['kol' + j]: document.getElementById(tableName).rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML, 
 'kol2': document.getElementById(tableName).rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML,
 'kol3': document.getElementById(tableName).rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML,
 'kol4': document.getElementById(tableName).rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML};

Comment: Seems like you are looping through the table rows. Please add that code in your post, so that others can also help.

Comment: yes i have a loop here but i part after ":" looks good so i just want to know how to get value for part before ":"